# Application cause Windows to crash, how to debug this kind of issue?

Tags: windows, debugging, crash-dumps

It is reported that one of our app process cause the windows system to crash, the only clue I got is the dump file under `C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP`, can anyone tell me how to debug this kind of issue please?

Answer (score 0):

You need [windbg](/questions/tagged/windbg), a free debugger from Microsoft which can analyze crash dump files.

For a basic analysis, use

```
.symfix
.reload
!analyze -v
```

I would need more details to give further advice. Usually googling for some of the output of above commands will give you an answer over at [superuser.com](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score -2):

C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP - this file totally related to RAM so these type errors totally due to RAM damage so checkout RAM chip or make use of another RAM chip for some time and try if error solve then no problem otherwise by making use of task manager terminate that process first and then find out exact reason for memory dump

Comment: Hello Dnyaneshwar, thanks very much for your comment. In fact, our user turned to Microsoft support first when he got this problem, but microsoft said according to the dump, the culprit is our process. They did not provide any specific reason, But I can also see our process name printed in the windbg output after I imported the dump file and ran "!analyze -v".

Comment: Receiving a crash dump file does not necessarily mean you have a problem with a ram chip.  It's just an indication that your program has abnormally terminated.  If you have the dump file and the symbol files for the application, you should be able to narrow down the cause of the crash.  If it took down Windows, my guess is that it's a heap corruption error.